# How to simply call an Approval Process from Apex Class?

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process, approval-history

I have created an Approval Process on OSR__c object. Due to some sudden changes in the requirement, I need to call that approval process from an apex class. I saw the various posts regarding automatic submission/approval/rejection of the record but I dont need that much. Only thing I need is, how to call the approval process(already present in the org) using an apex class ?

Any suggestion/advice on this is really helpful !!
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to submit the approval request? Did [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm) not help?

```
// Create an approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = 
            new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
        req1.setObjectId(a.id);
        
        // Submit on behalf of a specific submitter
        req1.setSubmitterId(user1.Id); 
        
        // Submit the record to specific process and skip the criteria evaluation
        req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('PTO_Request_Process');
        req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
        
        // Submit the approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
```

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kFpBIAU).

Comment: But my question is, Why will I create an approval request or submit on behalf of others or submit for approval from code ? All this I am doing from my Front end org. I just need to call it from apex class. Is it not as easy as we call a class or method like this : (className.methodName(); ) ???

Comment: I don't know whether I completely get what you are trying to do. All we do finally is ` Approval.process(req)` - similar to what you mentioned. Rest of the statements is just the ceremony to send relevant arguments (setting a few things in the object before invoking the method). I don't know if there is any other way of shortening the call.